# Are all numbers greater than the product of their prime divisors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Saw a lemma in a lecture
for a number $M$, all prime divisors of $M\geq 2$so if $M$ has $t$ distinct prime divisors then $|M| > 2^t$
This only seems to follow from the title statement, is there proof for this?

Comment: It's false for $M=2$, but otherwise correct.

Comment: wait but why is it correct?

Comment: Well, what do *you* think?  This is something I think you should be able to figure out on your own.  Bearing in mind every number is a product of its prime factors, possibly to powers, the answer really should be.... well, what do *you* think?

Comment: Your header question doesn't match the question in the body.  Every square free number is equal to the product of its prime divisors, to address the question in the header.

Comment: All non-square-free numbers are greater than the product of their distinct prime divisors.  All square-free numbers are equal to the product of their distinct prime factors.

Comment: Question is wrong!  Should be $\ge$ not $\gt$.

Comment: $2$ answers despite several issues : Title does not match to body and the claim in the body is not correct either, moreover confusingly formulated "... M , all prime divisors of $M\ge 2$ , so ..."

Answer (score 1):

This should be obvious.

Every positive integer has a prime factorization.  So it may be written as $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}......p_t^{a_t}$ where $p_i$ are the distinct prime factors and $a_i$ are the power of the prime factors.

Now $p_i^{a_i} \ge p_i^1=p_i$ with equality holding if and only if $a_i = 1$.  So $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}......p_t^{a_t} \ge p_1p_2......p_t \ge 2\cdot 2\cdot ..... 2=2^t$.

So $n \ge p_1p_2......p_t=$ the product of it's prime factors (and is equal if and only if $n$ has no prime factors to more than $1$ power; that is if and only if $n$ is "squarefree" and has no square factors).

And $p_1p_2......p_t \ge 2^t$ with equality holding if and only if $t=1$ and $p_1 = 2$.